# Performance of Oracle .Net drivers

Tags: .net, oracle

I'm currently comparing the performance of 4 different Oracle .net drivers. ODP.Net, DataDirect, OraDirect and the Microsoft .Net driver.

It seems that the Microsoft driver is the slowest, the others being comparable with DataDirect faster than OraDirect which in turn is faster than ODP.Net.

The question I have is whether or not this is consistent with anyone elses experience. If DataDirect is the fastest, are there any gotchas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I have is that DataDirect appears to be the fastest.